# Proving that $f(x,y)=(2x^2-y)(y-x^2)$ has positive and negative function values in every neighborhood around $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

I want to show that $f(x,y)=(2x^2-y)(y-x^2)$ has positive and negative function values in every neighborhood around $(0,0)$.

Is my reasoning sufficient  to prove this claim?

On the one hand, I approached $(0,0)$ using $y=\sqrt{2}x^2$. Then, for all $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, we have:$$f(x,\sqrt{2}x^2)=(3\sqrt{2}-4)x^4>0$$ and on the other hand, I approached $(0,0)$ using $x=0$. Then, for  all $y\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$, we have:$$f(0,y)=-y^2<0$$

My reasoning is that you can get arbitrarily close to $(0,0)$ using both ways to approach $(0,0)$ which guarantee negative and positive function values. Is this sufficient?

Comment: Somewhat off-topic: just because I had trouble following your logic does not imply that your approach is invalid.  It could easily be my shortcoming.  Anyway, my approach is to have $x$ (and therefore $x^2$) approach $0$, with $y_1$ being selected as $< x^2$, and $y_2$ being selected so that $x^2 < y_2 < 2x^2$.  Clearly, in any neighborhood around $(0,0)$, you will be able to select suitable $x, y_1, y_2$.

Comment: I just checked on symbolic calculator, your argument is OK. [There may be a faster way to get positive values...]

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, I was going to say that any point along the line $x=0$ where $y < 0$ gives strictly positive values.

Comment: @Ugo But $f(0,-1)=-1,$ and generally $f(0,y)=-y^2$ whether $y$ is positive or negative. OP already said that.

Comment: Ah right, I suppose $x^2 < y < 2x^2$ works though. Or is there an easier choice for positive values.

Comment: So you're that the reasoning is  "flawless"?

Comment: @Analysis What I meant to say in my first comment (which I now re-iterate) is that yes, your reasoning is correct. I was only adding there *might* be an easier way to show it gets positive near the origin, but what you did *does* show that.

Comment: @Ugo Yes, in particular note $f(t,\frac{3}{2}t^2)=\frac{t^4}{4}.$ That looks a bit simpler than OP's example, but can't just multiply $x,y$ by 2 here since $f$ isn't homogeneous, in fact then it would give a negative.

Comment: @Ugo Just noticed a slight simplification: $f(2t,5t^2)=3t^4.$